# How to preserve the indentation when using standalone or preview?

Tags: preview, standalone

The following output has no correct paragraph indentation after incorporating `standalone` documentclass or `preview` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,preview]{standalone}
\parindent=12pt% does not work!

\begin{document}
The position of a particle moving along the $x$-axis is given as
\[
s_t=s_0+v_0t+\frac 1 2 at^2
\]
where $s_0$, $v_0$, $a$, and $t$ represent the initial position, initial speed, acceleration, and the time, respectively.
Even though you are not interested in physics, please be quiet.

And now \ldots
\end{document}
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `preview` environment uses `\@arrayparboxrestore` that kills the parindent, just like it happens in `minipage` and in `\parbox`.

You can restore the normal parindent by patching `\preview`:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\edef\keptparindent{\the\parindent}
\patchcmd{\preview}
  {\ignorespaces} %%% \preview ends with \ignorespaces
  {\parindent\keptparindent\ignorespaces}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
The position of a particle moving along the $x$-axis is given as
\[
s_t=s_0+v_0t+\frac 1 2 at^2
\]
where $s_0$, $v_0$, $a$, and $t$ represent the initial position, 
initial speed, acceleration, and the time, respectively.
Even though you are not interested in physics, please be quiet.

And now \ldots
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It should be regarded as a bug that have to be fixed for the next build. :-)

Comment: @GarbageCollector I don't think so. However `preview` and `standalone` should at least document it.

Comment: Why did the author design `minipage` and `parbox` without preserving  `\parindent`?

Comment: @GarbageCollector Ask Leslie Lamport. ;-) The idea is, I believe, to start in a well determined status.

Comment: Then it should be a bug. :-)