# \AddToHook{begindocument/end}{⟨code⟩}\begin{document} not equivalent to \begin{document}⟨code⟩?

Tags: indentation, standalone, parindent, lthooks

(This a follow up of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115090/18401) about indentation of paragraphs with the `standalone` class.)

The following MCE gives the expected result (indented paragraphs):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\newlength\keptparindent
\keptparindent=\parindent

\begin{document}
\parindent=\keptparindent

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.  Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne
tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\end{document}
```

But, if:

```
\begin{document}
\parindent=\keptparindent
```

is replaced by the (supposed) equivalent in-preamble instruction:

```
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{%
  \parindent=\keptparindent
}
\begin{document}
```

the paragraphs are not indented anymore:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\newlength\keptparindent
\keptparindent=\parindent


\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{%
  \parindent=\keptparindent
}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.  Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne
tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\end{document}
```

Why, and is it possible to have indented paragraphs with only a in-preamble instruction?

### Edit

Here is my *File List*

```
standalone.cls    2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
shellesc.sty    2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
 xkeyval.sty    2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
l3backend-pdftex.def    2023-11-09 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
 ***********
```

Comment: `\AfterEndEnvironment` inserts the code behind `\end{<environment>}`. You want `\AfterBeginEnvironment` or `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I corrected my question. The same problem occurs with `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}` so the question remains :)

Comment: @cabohah which versions are you using? I just updated TL23 and I don't get indentations using Denis' example that uses `\AddToHook`

Comment: @cabohah I added my file list (see daleif comment).

Comment: Ah, I see, there is still an adapted `standalone.cfg` in my search path. With the original one I also don't have an indent. Sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately `standalone` does not use hooks, but appends `\sa@cls@afterbegindocument` to `\document`. And this `\sa@cls@afterbegindocument` is used to do the `\standalone` and therefore activate `varwidth`. The resulting code in `\document` is:

```latex
\UseOneTimeHook {begindocument/end}
\ignorespaces
\sa@cls@afterbegindocument
```

So the `begindocument/end` hooks are executed *before* the code relevant for the missing indent.

As a workaround, you can use:

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\newlength\keptparindent
\keptparindent=\parindent

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{%
  \csname sa@cls@afterbegindocument\endcsname
  \let\sa@cls@afterbegindocument\relax
  \parindent=\keptparindent
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.  Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne
tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

Note:

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\newlength\keptparindent
\keptparindent=\parindent

\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{%
  \standalone
  \NewCommandCopy\STANDALONE\standalone
  \def\standalone{\RenewCommandCopy\standalone\STANDALONE}%
  \parindent=\keptparindent
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.  Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a,
magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne
tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\end{document}
```

would also be possible.

Comment: We should probably `firstaid` that ...

Comment: I see https://github.com/MartinScharrer/standalone/issues/3 also about the hook system, open for nearly a year - I'll mail Martin and ask him about likelihood of a change